# How can I search for backquotes?

Tags: support, search, markdown

I want to search for literal backquotes in questions and answers that do not serve as `<code>`-like markdown markup.

Neither a literal backquote `` ` ``, a double quoted `` "`" `` nor an escaped backquote work as expected.

Using symbolhound was not helpful, even if others believe this.

Comment: You might need to use SEDE for this one.

Comment: http://symbolhound.com/?q=%60&l=&e=&n=&u=stackoverflow.com

Comment: [This question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/249848/174278) or rather the comment to it helped.

Comment: Why was symbolhound not helpful?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Because with SQL I can better narrow down the cases I am interested in.